# How do I represent two forward slashes within quotation marks in C++?

Tags: c++, syntax-highlighting, atom-editor

The code:

```
const LSString& strProjectPath = wstrOutputDir.c_str() + LSString( L"//") + filepath.stem().c_str() + LSString(L"-") + wstrUuid.c_str() + LSString(L"//") + filepath.stem().c_str() + LSString(L".lsproj");
```

How should I write down the two forward slashes so everything after it isn't commented out? The strange is, I only face this problem in my current text editor, Atom. Everything looks fine in Visual Studio.

Comment: I suggest sublime text or keep using vs

Comment: Yes actually you can just try to change the theme of your editor.

Comment: Is there a problem when compiling the code, or only in how the code looks in Atom? If the latter, this is probably a bug in the editor (in which case, you should add the corresponding tags to your question).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an issue with your editor's syntax highlighting - nothing is actually commented out.

Answer (score 0):

> "How should I write down the two forward slashes so everything after it isn't commented out?"

[image: with-false-comment]

A solution is to escape one or both the slashes.

```
LSString(L"\//")
```

[image: without-false-comment]

Comment: Note, however, that the escape sequence ``\/`` is not required to do anything sensible. I don't know of an implementation where it doesn't simply mean `'/'`, but that is not required by the language definition.